# Amazon web services autoscale

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to use **lambda python function** to name my  group instances?
I want to name them in increasing order like hello1,hello2,hello3,etc.Can anyone tell how to use lambda function to name my autlscale groups?

I want to create instances..I want a function which will create them and give them name tag as..first instance name tag should be "hello1" second instance name tag should be "hello2" ..and so on... If any instance gets terminated ..say hello2 gets terminated then by autoscaling group formed, minimum number of instances is 2 ..therefore new instance will be created name it as hello2

Comment: Please avoid "how to" questions. Show some of the code you've written in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question to provide more information. For example, what do you mean by "my group instances" -- are they already existing, or do you want the Lambda function to create them? Is your requirement to provide all instances within an Auto Scaling group with a `Name` tag that has a common prefix and an increasing number? What should happen if there are 3 instances, then one is scaled-in (terminated), then another launched -- what number should the new instance be, should it be 3 (because there are 3 instances now) or 4 (because #3 was terminated)?

Comment: No...I want to create instances..I want a function which will  create them and give them name tag as..first instance name tag should be "hello1" second instance name tag should be "hello2" ..and so on... If any instance gets terminated ..say hello2 gets terminated then by autoscaling group formed, minimum number of instances is 2 ..therefore new instance will be created name it as hello2

Comment: @John Rotensein..please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to write a script that gets executed when the instance is started. Put the script in the **User Data** that automatically gets run when an instance starts.

The script would:

- Call `DescribeInstances()` to obtain a list of EC2 instances
- Filter the list down to the instances within the Auto Scaling group
- Count the number of instances (including itself)
- Perform the necessary logic to figure out which number should be assigned
- Create a `Name` tag on the new instance (effectively tagging itself)

Please note that the numbers might not be continuous. For example:

- Start 4 instances (1, 2, 3, 4)
- Auto Scaling might remove instances 2 & 3
- Auto Scaling might add an instance (call it #2)
- The current instances are: 1, 2, 4

**Bottom line:** You really shouldn't get fixated over numbering instances that are ephemeral (that is, that can be removed at any time). Simply be aware of *how many* instances are in the Auto Scaling group. If you really do need a unique ID, use the `InstanceId`.